# Will deploying Rails using Torquebox on Openshift present any advantages over deploying Rails directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jboss, openshift, torquebox

I am looking at two options for deploying a Rails application on OpenShift.

I can either directly deploy it or setup Torquebox and deploy my Rails application using it. Does one options present a significant performance advantage over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TorqueBox is much faster than the original Ruby. Not only the interpreter (JRuby) is faster, simply because it runs on JVM and uses JIT and JVM's fine-tuned garbage collector, but also it uses  additional features available in JVM, like parallel threading etc.

More, with TorqueBox, you have JBoss AS services at hand when you decide to use them, which I guess you will, if your app grows.

Reference: http://torquebox.org/news/2011/10/06/torquebox-2x-performance/